# What's the quickest/easiest way to get example data into ListView/GridView in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, rapid-prototyping

I'm doing some quick design work/rapid prototyping with WPF. I'm curious if anyone has a good strategy for getting example data into a `ListView`/`GridView` (or really any `ItemsControl` for that matter). The example data would either be made up on the fly, or pasted in from somewhere (e.g., an Excel file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the [XMLDataProvider.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx).

This way you can type the data directly into the XAML.

See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409842/listbox-content-not-completely-stretching-across-listbox) for an example.

Comment: I like this, thanks! I had thought of using an XmlDataProvider, but I didn't realize it was so easy to include the data right in the XAML.