# How do I highlight a treeview selected item with some color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, selecteditem

I have a treeview in WPF. I want a different color when i select the treeviewitem.

Comment: I think this is more-or-less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388232/ ... the same trick I've used in that answer will apply to TreeView.

Comment: @MattHamilton and hevgen are both correct. Use the code sample in Matt's link. It works fine with TreeViews. OP, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Simple Trigger in *TreeView.ItemContainerStyle* can't help for default TreeView template.

For standard template highlighting is done via background changing for specific  element inside TreeView template. This specific element is not accessible for programmer without TreeView template changing. By default resource  is used to set background on this element for highlighting.

So there are few ways:

1. simple (but side effects possible): redefine resource with key **{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}** for TreeView or *ItemsPanel* template;
2. Redefine complete Template for TreeView.

Answer (score -1):

Try following code. It should work.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```