# TreeView.IsSelected trigger does not work properly

Tags: wpf, triggers, treeview, itemtemplate

I am trying to change SelectedItem template in TreeView.
I wrote simple container style and change item template in Style.Triggers as described

[1]: [How do I highlight a treeview selected item with some color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876759/how-do-i-highlight-a-treeview-selected-item-with-some-color) or

[2]: [WPF TreeView: How to style selected items with rounded corners like in Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047576/wpf-treeview-how-to-style-selected-items-with-rounded-corners-like-in-explorer) but it doesn't work.

Then I created a new project and created TreeView with a simple style and template

```
<TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item1" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item2" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item3"/>

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="selectedTemplate">
                <StackPanel Height="25">
                    <TextBlock Text="SelectedItem"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource selectedTemplate}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

So, then I selected TreeViewItem in tree view FontWeight, FontStyle and Foreground are changed, but Background and ItemTemplate doesn't changed.

Result: [image: here]

Could you explain this strange behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ItemTemplate` property affects children elements and not the item itself. And background is set to default selection background for `Border` that adornes the content, so the green color underneath is not visible. 
You can achieve your goals like this:

```
 <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item1" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item2" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item3"/>

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="selectedTemplate">
                <StackPanel Height="25">
                    <TextBlock Text="SelectedItem" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource selectedTemplate}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```