# TreeView shows blue for selected item

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a treeview structure. When I try to click on the nodes there is a blue color that shows the node selected. How can I remove that. 
 I don't want a selection color to be displayed on the tree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I highlight a treeview selected item with some color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876759/how-do-i-highlight-a-treeview-selected-item-with-some-color)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`ItemContainerStyle` method does not work for me say on Windows-8. There are 4 brushes that generally correspond to this and are used by the default Template for `TreeViewItem`

**keys:**

`HighlightBrushKey` - Background with focus.

`HighlightTextBrushKey`  - Foreground with focus.

`InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` - Background without focus.

`InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` - Foreground without focus.

Just override them as you see fit, for your requirement something like this would do fine:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                      Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                      Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                      Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                      Color="Black" />
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Do pay attention to only overriding them within the scope you require. For example if you put all this into App.xaml you're going to see some weird side-effects as all control's using these Brushes would now end up using your overridden ones which may not be what you're after.

Comment: Please note that `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` and `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` is only for .NET 4.5 or later.