# Different "IsSelected" color for each node on TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a `TreeView` that presents several different datatypes in a hierarchy.  I have multiple `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s defined in my `UserControl.Resources`, which I use to alter the look of each node depending on its datatype:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyFirstType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        ....
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MySecondType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        ....
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    .... etc ....

</UserControl.Resources>
```

I'd like to have each type of node have a different hover and selected color.  However, all of the examples I've found on changing these colors ([for example, this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814308/treeview-shows-blue-for-selected-item)) involve changing a few system-defined resources, like `HighlightBrushKey`.  Since I don't have access to the `TreeViewItem`s being generated by my `TreeView`, how do I go about overriding these resource values on a per-item basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplish that by setting the `SystemColors` that you mentioned to make the `SelectedItem Background Transparent` and then declaring my items in `Border` elements so that I can set their `Background` colours individually using a `DataTrigger` and a `RelativeSource Binding`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
```

...

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyFirstType}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <Border>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={
                        RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" 
                        Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
    <!-- Your content here -->
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This was my backup option in case I wasn't able to alter the system colors; so far it looks like the only working solution.