# listbox design issue

Tags: wpf, listbox

i am trying to design some nice listbox, but every time i click on the item in the listbox
a selection background is ruined everything...
how can i make it irrelevant ?

this is the XAML:

```
<!-- Site List View -->
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="SiteListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Gainsboro" Offset="0.805" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ListBox.Background>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="DarkRed" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" CornerRadius="4"
                        Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={
                        RelativeSource
                        Mode=FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}
                        }}">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

a also attached a print screen.[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to redefine the colour for selected items. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388232/wpf-listbox-image-selected-the-saga-continues/388313#388313

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: Just noticed you had answered the same thing as I did but in a comment. You should have posted an answer instead, didn't mean to steal your answer :)

Comment: @Meleak Didn't think it was worth duplicating the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default colors for when a `ListBoxItem` container `IsSelected`. Set them to `Transparent` to get the effect that you're after

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <!-- Brush for selected item that doesn't have focus -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <!-- Brush for selected item that has focus -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</ListBox>
```